# Objects instantiating at Run Time, but with a delay between each object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What I want to do is instantiate a prefab in a circle, but over time. So that one prefab will appear and the others will appear over time. Should I be using a coroutine to achieve this effect?

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class Fire_Circle : MonoBehaviour
 {

 public GameObject prefab;
 public int numberOfObjects = 20;
 public float radius = 5f;
 public float height;
 void Start()
 {
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)

    {

        float angle = i * Mathf.PI * 2 / numberOfObjects;
        Vector3 pos = new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(angle),  height / radius, 
        Mathf.Sin(angle)) * radius;
        Instantiate(prefab, pos, prefab.transform.rotation );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what about a timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coroutines are certainly a nice option:

```
void Start()
{
   StartCoroutine(SpawnObjs());
}

IEnumerator SpawnObjs()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
    {
        float angle = i * Mathf.PI * 2 / numberOfObjects;
        Vector3 pos = new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(angle),  height / radius, 
        Mathf.Sin(angle)) * radius;
        Instantiate(prefab, pos, prefab.transform.rotation );
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.8f);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works but you don't even have to start a coroutine in the Start method, you can also use the Start method itself as a "coroutine" by returning IEnumerator  instead of void.

Comment: @R1PFake True but the ryeMoss's current method is more useful since it shows OP how to start a coroutine.

Comment: This works perfect - it is exactly how I want this script to work. Thank you @ryeMoss